# Calling Karate feature files based on SOAP response status code 200 or 500

Tags: karate

I have a requirement where I needed to call multiple feature files based on status code 200, 201, 500 etc. I tried few examples listed in stackoverflow as well but didn't help.

E.g.
Let's say I created 3 feature files. File1.feature, File2.feature & File3.feature.

1) File1.feature may give response status code 200 or 500

2) Based on response code 200, I need to call File2.feature to do certain tests.

3) Based on response code 500, I need to call File3.feature to do certain tests.

Appreciate your help on this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After any request, there is a "magic variable" called [`responseStatus`](https://github.com/intuit/karate#responsestatus) that will hold the HTTP status code value. You can easily use it to do conditional calls.

```
* if (responseStatus == 200) karate.call('some.feature')
```

Refer: https://github.com/intuit/karate#conditional-logic

Comment: Thanks a lot, this worked with minor change on '* if.. ' with '* eval if.. '.  I am able to proceed with java integration on subsequent features.

Comment: @SharathChandran `if` will work in 0.9.5.RC3 onwards

Comment: Thank you for that info.